# How To Make Div With 100% Height Extend into Scroll Overflow in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have a `div` in HTML that has two child `div`s, one on the right and one on the left. Both child `div`s have `contenteditable` set, so when the user click in them they can type. However, when the text goes below the size of the `div`, the parent `div` overflows and scrolls, but the child `div`s don't.

Here is an example:

```css
#container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: scroll;
    color: white;
    background: gray;
}
#part1 {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0;
    background: blue;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    overflow: visible;
}
#part2 {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0;
    background: green;
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<div id="part1" contenteditable="true"></div>
<div id="part2" contenteditable="true"></div>
</div>
```

In the above example, try typing more text than can fit vertically (by spamming the enter key while inside the box). Once the text goes over the side of the box, the parent overflows like it is supposed to, however, the children (which are being typed into) don't, even though they have 100% height.

Is there a way to make the children extend WITH the parent, so they both scroll together when one/both overflows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very good for your task to use the rules of *flexibility*. Add `display: flex` and `flex-flow: wrap` for `#container`. And remove the `height: 100%` from the children, because `flex-flow: wrap` itself will stretch the elements to the *full* height.

Also, remove `float: left` and `overflow: visible` from children.

```css
#container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: scroll;
    color: white;
    background: gray;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: wrap;
}

#part1 {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0;
    background: blue;
    /*height: 100%;
    float: left;
    overflow: visible;*/
}

#part2 {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0;
    background: green;
    /*height: 100%;
    float: right;
    overflow: visible;*/
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="part1" contenteditable="true"></div>
    <div id="part2" contenteditable="true"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It does not work, contrary to the code sample below by @biberman but with fixed height..

Answer (score 0):

You could change `height` to `min-height` for the inner divs and use an additional inner div with `display: flex` so that both colored divs have the same growing height. `overflow: visible` is not necessary.

**Working example:**

```css
#container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: scroll;
  color: white;
  background: gray;
}

#inner {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 200px;
}

#part1 {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  background: blue;
  min-height: 100%;
  float: left;
}

#part2 {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  background: green;
  min-height: 100%;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="inner">
    <div id="part1" contenteditable="true"></div>
    <div id="part2" contenteditable="true"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Since you define some css twice and overflow-x is not necessary you can add a class to the colored divs and set the overflow for the container only to `overflow-y`.

**Working example:**

```css
#container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  color: white;
  background: gray;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#inner {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 200px;
}

.editable {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
}

#part1 {
  background: blue;
  float: left;
}

#part2 {
  background: green;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="inner">
    <div class="editable" id="part1" contenteditable="true"></div>
    <div class="editable" id="part2" contenteditable="true"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```